# Maximum Entropy / Principle of Insufficient Reason

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a question about the maximum entropy principle and its implications.  Here's the problem that motivates my question:

Suppose, for instance, I have a random variable $X$ which takes on the value +1 with probability p and -1 with probability 1-p.  Knowing nothing else about the distribution, we might decide to maximize $H(p)=-\sum p_i \log p_i = -(p \log(p) + (1-p) \log (1-p))$ to determine p, which is pretty easy to do with basic calculus- we wind up with $p^*=\frac12$, which is the same result dictated by the Principle of Insufficient Reason.  It seems intuitive to me (this is where I think things start to get somewhat un-rigorous), that another way to think about this is to imagine that $p$ is itself a random variable drawn from $P  \approx \text{Uniform(0,1)}$, and so $p^*$ is simply the "most likely" value of $P$, $\mathbb{E}[P]=\frac12$, which agrees with our prior result.

Now, here's my actual question.  Suppose I have some solid theoretical reason to assume that $X$ is more likely to assume +1 than -1, i.e. $p>1-p$.  When I try to maximize $H(P)$ under the constraint that $p>1/2$, the problem becomes ill-posed- the function approaches its maximum at the boundary condition, which it can never reach- the "answer" is $p^* = \frac12 + \epsilon$.  But, under the other interpretation holding p as a random variable, this problem can be posed as $p^* = \mathbb{E}[\max(P,1-P)]=\frac34$, which is a well-defined answer and seems like a "reasonable" solution: if we know that $p^*$ is between 1/2 and 1, then the midpoint of the two can't be an unreasonable guess.

Why does this seeming paradox occur?  Is there any theoretical answer that allows us to assign a "nice" probability like $\frac23$ or $\frac34$ to the question, or are we stuck with stating that the BC $p>1-p$ adds no new information, since the optimal entropy is still essentially the same?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, there isn't - this is a good example to showcase the problems one might face when trying to implement the maximum entropy principle, under *inequality* constraints (the initial formulation of the principle used only equality constraints). Still "the maximum entropy solution" is *not* that $p^*=1/2$, because our prior admitted information is that $p$ should be strictly higher than $1/2$.
Then, the solution *is* of the form $p^* = \frac 12 + \epsilon, \;\;\epsilon >0$, however inconvenient that might be. In *practice*, $\epsilon$ should be chosen as a very small number (but not zero), since by increasing its value we decrease the entropy of the distribution, in an unjustifiable way, given that we only know that $p> 1/2$, nothing more.

But if $\epsilon$ is such a small number, does it really matter? It may matter a lot. The expected value of the random variable will be

$$E(X) = \left(\frac 12 + \epsilon\right)\cdot 1 + \left(1-\frac 12 - \epsilon\right)\cdot(-1) = 2\epsilon$$
Already we have doubled this very small number. Now assume that $X$ is the typical element of an i.i.d. stochastic process, which models the *net* emissions of a dangerous air-born chemical compound (in whatever suitable units), which is the by-product of one monthly cycle of an industrial process. The emissions are *net*, because the industry has in place a procedure to *clean* the air also (hence the possible value $-1$). We are interested in expected 10-year concentration, so we are interested in the sum of these ranodm variables, $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{120}X_i$. Under $p^*=1/2$, obviously $E(Z\mid p=1/2) = 0$. But under $p^* = \frac 12 + \epsilon$, we obtain
$$E(Z\mid p=1/2 + \epsilon) = 240\epsilon$$

This may be high, given any regulatory standards in place. Of course, the arbitrary value of $\epsilon$ makes things problematic: $0.001$ is a small number, but so is $0.00001$. What to do? Well, in *practice* again, one will attempt to acquire more information in order to bound $p$ from below with a sharp boundary value higher than $1/2$, by, for example, measuring the actual compound concentration for some period of time before concluding on the parameter value to be used.